# Reading memory from Bluestacks

Tags: c#, android, bluestacks

I'm trying to read memory from a game emulated with Bluestacks using Cheat Engine, although the only information I could find was that I should read the physical memory instead of attaching to the Bluestacks process. Reading physical memory resulted in no matches found for the memory address I was trying to locate, it would also produce BSOD on my machine.

After viewing videos of bots for popular games like "Clash of Clans" I see debug messages in their software like

> Attached to process BLSTCKS

Is it possible to read memory from Bluestacks using Cheat Engine / C#? What would be the best approach to relay that information back to Windows?

**EDIT**

Using Cheat Engine as proof of concept before I begin developing my application in C#

Comment: Can you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467311/c-sharp-readprocessmemory-how-to-read-a-64-bit-memory-address

Comment: Jason, did you find a solution to your question?